# I want to generate 2 excel files for the user to download: one succeeds but the other one does not

Tags: php, excel, download

I have this code:

```
<?php require_once '../include/Classes/PHPExcel.php' ?>
<?php require_once '../include/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php' ?>
<?php require_once '../include/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php' ?>
$PHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$PHPExcel = $reader->load("path");

............work on setting the excel

$PHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$PHPExcelWriter->save($filename . '.xlsx');

$PHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($PHPExcel);
if (file_exists($filename . '.xlsx')) {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$filename.xlsx\"");
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename . '.xlsx'));
    header('Pragma: no-cache');
    header('Expires: 0');
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    @readfile($filename . '.xlsx');
    exit;
}
```

This one is succeed.And the file can be downloaded by user to there computer but not only store the file in localhost.

```
if (isset($_POST['Export1']) && $_POST['Export1'] == 'Export to Excel') {
        $invoice_id = $_POST['invoice_id'];
        $invoice_date = $_POST['invoice_date'];
        $event_code = $_POST['event_code'];
        //$total_price = $_POST['total_price'];
        //$total_discount = $_POST['total_discount'];
        $total_amount = $_POST['total_amount'];
        $invoice_code = $_POST['invoice_code'];

        $bill_to = $_POST['bill_to'];
        $prog_sub = $_POST['prog_sub'];
        $temp_prog_sub = explode('-', $prog_sub);
        $program = $temp_prog_sub[0];
        $subject = $temp_prog_sub[1];
        $init_first_row = 15;

        $PHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
        $reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $PHPExcel = $reader->load("../include/Classes/Invoice_In-school.xlsx"); // sample is your file name 
        $PHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Pathways");
        $PHPExcel->getProperties()->setTitle("In-School Invoice");

        $PHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D7', $bill_to);
        $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD7', $invoice_date);
        $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD9', $invoice_code); //place a invoice_code here
        $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D12', $program . ' ' . $subject . '(' . $event_code . ')');
        //$PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('K24', '$' .$total_price);
        //$PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('Q24', '$' .$total_discount);
        $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('AD25', '$' . $total_amount);

        if (isset($_POST['activity_id'])) {
            for ($j = 0; $j < count($_POST['activity_id']); $j++) {
                $amount = $_POST['amount'][$j];
                $date = $_POST['date'][$j];
                $start_time = $_POST['start_time'][$j];
                $end_time = $_POST['end_time'][$j];

                (String) $date_col = 'A' . $init_first_row;
                (String) $time_col = 'N' . $init_first_row;
                (String) $amount_col = 'AD' . $init_first_row;

                $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $date_col, $date); 
                $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $time_col, $start_time . '-' . $end_time); 

                $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $amount_col, '$' . $amount);

                $init_first_row++;
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['activity_id'])) {
            $no_of_act = count($_POST['activity_id']);
        } else {
            $no_of_act = 0;
        }
        $i = $_POST['i'];
        $i-=$no_of_act;
        for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++) {
            $j+=$no_of_act;
            $amount = $_POST['amount'][$j];
            $date = $_POST['date'][$j];
            $start_time = $_POST['start_time'][$j];
            $end_time = $_POST['end_time'][$j];

            (String) $date_col = 'A' . $init_first_row;
            (String) $time_col = 'N' . $init_first_row;
            (String) $amount_col = 'AD' . $init_first_row;

            $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $date_col, $date); //date
            $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $time_col, $start_time . '-' . $end_time); //time
            $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue((String) $amount_col, '$' . $amount);

            $init_first_row++;
            $j-=$no_of_act;
        }
        //ob_start();
        $filename="XXXXX";
        $PHPExcelWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($PHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
        $PHPExcelWriter->save($filename . '.xlsx');

        $PHPExcel->disconnectWorksheets();
        unset($PHPExcel);
        if (file_exists($filename . '.xlsx')) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"$invoice_code.xlsx\"");
            header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
            //header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename . '.xlsx'));
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            ob_clean();
            flush();
            @readfile($filename . '.xlsx');
            exit;
        }
        echo("<script>location.href ='XXXXXXX.php';</script>");
    }
```

And this one fail.And output this:

```
PK��D$�Hp�[Content_Types].xml���N�0E�|E�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ؓƪ_g���$R�v'J�=���&[k�5D�ޕlXXNz�ݢdo���e��S�x%����j4����KV��9GY�X���T>Z��1.xr)�o�[.�K�R�6�
...
```

And the fail one is more complex i tried to use ob_start(); but not work.
Please help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Is the file that is being saved to the filesystem in the second scenario correct? Knowing that might help you track down whether or not the issue is with creating your file or serving it to the user.

Comment: @WaikiChung, what **EXACTLY** do you mean that the second one *fails*? For what I see it produces excel file correctly ("PK" signature, "[Content_Types].xml" etc.).

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski Yes the second one fails and it redirect to the page that contains the unreadable characters

Comment: @chandlermania The file is being saved in localhost and can being downloaded in the first scenario and the file is being saved in localhost but fail to be downloaded and output the unreadable characters in the second one.

Comment: @WaikiChung, are BOTH files served from the same server and downloaded by using the same web browser? This looks like a problem with HTTP server or web browser, not your code. Code works correctly - it generates XLSX file with PK signature and all other data.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski Yes, same server and same web browser:FireFox and IE.

Comment: Try setting Content-Type as `application/octet-stream` and test if it works. Do not write anything about `charset`.

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski  
try:
header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
//header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8;');

but fail

Comment: @WaikiChung, it seems that you have to provide us with more data. Is this possible for you to share your code on GIT or similar site?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski i updated the second one , all my code is here .

Comment: @WaikiChung, your code seems to be correct - I've tested in on Chrome 36, Firefox 29, Internet Explorer 8 and it works fine even with `application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=UTF-8`. I would suspect that something must be not right with your HTTP server then, but I don't know how to debug it. Is your site online? What web server do you use?

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski My site is not placed in web server . I use XAMPP in localhost server to test the file and in first scenario which is successful is in under the same server.....

Comment: @WaikiChung, honestly, I don't know what to do next. I've tested it on XAMPP 1.7.4 and it works fine. Unfortunately, I don't know how to help you. :-(

Comment: @GrzegorzAdamKowalski Nevermind......